# At what point is a question not useful to others?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I've already asked this question on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274830/at-what-point-is-a-question-not-useful-to-others), but I was [told](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18245978#18245978) that this question is good for all Stack Exchange, so I'm asking it here, too.

I've been working on translating a program line for line from Turbo Pascal to C, but I've apparently made some mistakes, and the version I copied from wasn't a perfect transcription of the original program. I'd like to ask about certain sections of code that I believe have a mistake within them, but on the other hand, I could swear that I read somewhere (though I can't find it now) that questions are supposed to be useful for more than just yourself.

At what point should I just struggle to work out the answer myself rather than asking it here? Am I just imagining that I read that somewhere?

Comment: What is the etiquette on re-asking questions like this? Should I copy over the other answer?

Comment: You should always try yourself first, ask later if you get stuck and hit a solid wall.

Comment: If the information in the question can be of use to future readers, it's appropriate here. If it's specific to the software you're translating, and has no general value as a programming topic, it's not appropriate. In other words, we're not going to do the work of line-by-line translations for you; if the *general* question can apply to others, ask. If you want specific help porting lines of code, don't - SO isn't a "translate my code from language A to language B for me" site.

Comment: @KenWhite The issue is actually that the thing builds and runs perfectly fine, but doesn't work as intended.

Comment: That's not the question you asked here. If it builds and runs perfectly fine, but doesn't work, you have an actual problem. You asked about line-by-line translations, and that's the point I addressed. Just like SO, you need to be specific here about what you're asking. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite I was actually hoping that the question was as broad as the title is. :-/

Comment: There is no "specific definition". The definition is simple: either the information (and answers) will be useful to others in the future (IOW, has some general applicability), in which case it's appropriate here, or it doesn't (in which case it's not). These sites are for building a knowledge base. If in the process of collecting that knowledge your particular problem is solved, that's great, but the purpose of the site is not to solve one individual's problem.